# Hadoop : HortonWorks SandBox Installation : Not able to launch Dashboard(Ambari Interface) from Splash page due to Authorization failure

Tags: ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

Referring to below  link Installed Hortonworks Sandbox on Oracle VM Virtual box. 
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox

After starting the VM , Connected to host IP on port 2222 using Putty as user root. Changed Admin password successfully. Checked the status of Ambari Server and found in started state.

loaded the Splash page successfully on the URL http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8888

Now While loading Dashboard on URL http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8080/main/dashboard/metrics  , Authorization popup not accepting Any of the UserId/Password combinations provided on HortornWorks website(link provided earlier)

I tried with admin/"My Password" and maria_dev/maria_dev and raj_ops/raj_ops. Authorization getting failed for every set of userid/pwd.

I have checked the port forwarding is enabled for port 8080 on VM Machine. Any further pointers appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to know..... well, how to ask.

Comment: More Information Provided.

Comment: did you even bother to read that link? how did you encounter the problem, what did you do to solve it, what do you think is wrong, then finally tell us your problem

Comment: only then can we actually help you in a manner that _you_ find useful

Comment: I am afraid , I can not be any more detailed than my recent updates. Please let me know what specific question you have , should you have any.

Comment: raj_ops/raj_ops is correct, and changing the password in Putty has nothing to do with that account

Comment: I changed the password of Admin (As suggested in official website)and not raj_ops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed on VMWare instead of VirtualBox and It worked. Was able to launch and login to Ambari.